# Real meaning of the 3rd parameter of _IOR

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have one driver and daemon, daemon access driver using *ioctl*, I am a bit confused about the third parameter of `_IOR`:

```
#define _IOR(type,nr,size)  _IOC(_IOC_READ,(type),(nr),(_IOC_TYPECHECK(size)))
```

I have some code as following,
*ioctl* cmd defetnition:

```
#define TEST_GET_NUM_A  _IOR(TESTIO, 0x01, uint8_t *)
#define TEST_GET_NUM_B  _IOR(TESTIO, 0x02, uint8_t)
```

*ioctl* in driver:

```
case TEST_GET_NUM_A:
    rc = put_user(data->num_keys, (uint8_t __user *) arg);
    break;
case TEST_GET_NUM_B:
    rc = put_user(data->num_keys, (uint8_t __user *) arg);
    break;
```

*ioctl* in daemon:

```
uint8_t num_keys = 0;
rc = ioctl(fd, TEST_GET_NUM_A/TEST_GET_NUM_B, &num_keys);
if (rc < 0) {
    ALOGE("ioctl failed %d", rc);
    close(fd);
    return rc;
}
```

both `TEST_GET_NUM_A` and `TEST_GET_NUM_B` work well, no crash happen. 
My question is which one is correct one, or both?

`_IOR(type,nr,size)` size means the size of 3rd parameter in `ioctl(fd, TEST_GET_NUM_A/B, &num_keys)` or means the size of the data passed from kernel to user space?

Answer (score 2):

The size of the type becomes part of the ioctl number. This is intended to catch errors where the kernel and userspace accidentally use different types (or different definitions of the same type).

But that field has no effect on the behaviour of the ioctl (unless your driver explicitly reads it).